# Dimensional error in the non-linguistic dataset as input to LSTM based Encoder-decoder model using attention

Tags: multidimensional-array, lstm, tf.keras, attention-model, encoder-decoder

I'm trying to implement attention -LSTM based encoder decoder model for multi-class classification. The dataset is non-linguistic in nature.
Characteristics of my dataset:

```
    x_train.shape = (930,5)
    y_train.shape = (405,5)
    x_test.shape = (930,3)
    y_test.shape = (405,3)

    x_train.head()
        val1    val2    val3    val4    val5
        10000   00101   01000   10000   00110
        10000   00101   01000   10000   00110
        00010   01001   01001   01000   00110
        00100   01000   01001   01000   00111
        00101   01000   01001   01000   00110
```

Then I converted the dataframe values into array:

```
    x_tr = np.array(x_train)
    array([['10000', '00101', '01000', '10000', '00110'],
           ['10000', '00101', '01000', '10000', '00110'],
           ['00010', '01001', '01001', '01000', '00110'],
           ...,
           ['01001', '00101', '01001', '01001', '00110'],
           ['00101', '01000', '01001', '01000', '00110'],
           ['00100', '01000', '01001', '01000', '00111']], dtype=object)
```

Then I reshaped my array into 3D, so that it can be given as an input to the LSTM based enc-dec model:

```
    X_TR = np.reshape(x_tr, (930, 5, -1))
    Y_TR = np.reshape(y_tr, (930, 3, -1))
    X_TE = np.reshape(x_te, (405, 5, -1))
    Y_TE = np.reshape(y_te, (405, 3, -1))
    
    print(X_TR.shape, x_tr.shape)
    (930, 5, 1) (930, 5)
```

Now I define the simple model, but get the error pasted below the code

```
    def main():
        time_steps, input_dim, output_dim = 5, 5, 3
        model_input = Input(shape=(time_steps, input_dim))
        x = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(model_input)
        x = Attention(32)(x)
        x = Dense(1)(x)
        model = Model(model_input, x)
        model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
        print(model.summary())
        model.fit(X_TR, Y_TR, epochs=10)
    
        # test save/reload model.
        pred1 = model.predict(X_TE)
       
        np.testing.assert_almost_equal(pred1, Y_TE)
        print('Success.')
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The output is as follows:

```
    Model: "model"
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
    ==================================================================================================
    input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 5, 5)]       0                                            
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    lstm (LSTM)                     (None, 5, 64)        17920       input_1[0][0]                    
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    last_hidden_state (Lambda)      (None, 64)           0           lstm[0][0]                       
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    attention_score_vec (Dense)     (None, 5, 64)        4096        lstm[0][0]                       
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    attention_score (Dot)           (None, 5)            0           last_hidden_state[0][0]          
                                                                     attention_score_vec[0][0]        
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    attention_weight (Activation)   (None, 5)            0           attention_score[0][0]            
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    context_vector (Dot)            (None, 64)           0           lstm[0][0]                       
                                                                     attention_weight[0][0]           
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    attention_output (Concatenate)  (None, 128)          0           context_vector[0][0]             
                                                                     last_hidden_state[0][0]          
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    attention_vector (Dense)        (None, 128)          16384       attention_output[0][0]           
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense (Dense)                   (None, 1)            129         attention_vector[0][0]           
    ==================================================================================================
    Total params: 38,529
    Trainable params: 38,529
    Non-trainable params: 0
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    None
    Epoch 1/10
    WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function.<locals>.train_function at 0x000002813E5532F0> and will run it as-is.
    Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
    Cause: 'arguments' object has no attribute 'posonlyargs'
    To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
    WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_train_function.<locals>.train_function at 0x000002813E5532F0> and will run it as-is.
    Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
    Cause: 'arguments' object has no attribute 'posonlyargs'
    To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
    WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 5, 5) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 5, 1).
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
        446     program_ctx = converter.ProgramContext(options=options)
    --> 447     converted_f = _convert_actual(target_entity, program_ctx)
        448     if logging.has_verbosity(2):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in _convert_actual(entity, program_ctx)
        283 
    --> 284   transformed, module, source_map = _TRANSPILER.transform(entity, program_ctx)
        285 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\transpiler.py in transform(self, obj, user_context)
        285     if inspect.isfunction(obj) or inspect.ismethod(obj):
    --> 286       return self.transform_function(obj, user_context)
        287 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\transpiler.py in transform_function(self, fn, user_context)
        469           # TODO(mdan): Confusing overloading pattern. Fix.
    --> 470           nodes, ctx = super(PyToPy, self).transform_function(fn, user_context)
        471 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\transpiler.py in transform_function(self, fn, user_context)
        362     node = self._erase_arg_defaults(node)
    --> 363     result = self.transform_ast(node, context)
        364 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in transform_ast(self, node, ctx)
        251     unsupported_features_checker.verify(node)
    --> 252     node = self.initial_analysis(node, ctx)
        253 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in initial_analysis(self, node, ctx)
        239     node = qual_names.resolve(node)
    --> 240     node = activity.resolve(node, ctx, None)
        241     node = reaching_definitions.resolve(node, ctx, graphs)
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\static_analysis\activity.py in resolve(node, context, parent_scope)
        708 def resolve(node, context, parent_scope=None):
    --> 709   return ActivityAnalyzer(context, parent_scope).visit(node)
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\transformer.py in visit(self, node)
        444 
    --> 445       result = super(Base, self).visit(node)
        446 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\ast.py in visit(self, node)
        252         visitor = getattr(self, method, self.generic_visit)
    --> 253         return visitor(node)
        254 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\static_analysis\activity.py in visit_FunctionDef(self, node)
        578       # Argument annotartions (includeing defaults) affect the defining context.
    --> 579       node = self._visit_arg_annotations(node)
        580 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\static_analysis\activity.py in _visit_arg_annotations(self, node)
        554     self._track_annotations_only = True
    --> 555     node = self._visit_arg_declarations(node)
        556     self._track_annotations_only = False
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\static_analysis\activity.py in _visit_arg_declarations(self, node)
        559   def _visit_arg_declarations(self, node):
    --> 560     node.args.posonlyargs = self._visit_node_list(node.args.posonlyargs)
        561     node.args.args = self._visit_node_list(node.args.args)
    
    AttributeError: 'arguments' object has no attribute 'posonlyargs'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-8f7d95d574b4> in <module>
         20 
         21 if __name__ == '__main__':
    ---> 22     main()
    
    <ipython-input-6-8f7d95d574b4> in main()
          8     model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
          9     print(model.summary())
    ---> 10     model.fit(X_TR, Y_TR, epochs=10)
         11 
         12     # test save/reload model.
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
       1079                 _r=1):
       1080               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
    -> 1081               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
       1082               if data_handler.should_sync:
       1083                 context.async_wait()
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
        826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
        827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
    --> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
        829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
        830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
        869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
        870       initializers = []
    --> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
        872     finally:
        873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
        724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
        725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    --> 726             *args, **kwds))
        727 
        728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2974       args, kwargs = None, None
       2975     with self._lock:
    -> 2976       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
       2977     return graph_function
       2978 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
       3369 
       3370           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
    -> 3371           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
       3372           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
       3373 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
       3214             arg_names=arg_names,
       3215             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
    -> 3216             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
       3217         self._function_attributes,
       3218         function_spec=self.function_spec,
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
        988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
        989 
    --> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
        991 
        992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
        632             xla_context.Exit()
        633         else:
    --> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
        635         return out
        636 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        971                     recursive=True,
        972                     optional_features=autograph_options,
    --> 973                     user_requested=True,
        974                 ))
        975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
        452     if is_autograph_strict_conversion_mode():
        453       raise
    --> 454     return _fall_back_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, e)
        455 
        456   with StackTraceMapper(converted_f), tf_stack.CurrentModuleFilter():
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in _fall_back_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, exc)
        499     logging.warn(warning_template, f, file_bug_message, exc)
        500 
    --> 501   return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
        502 
        503 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
        476 
        477   if kwargs is not None:
    --> 478     return f(*args, **kwargs)
        479   return f(*args)
        480 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_function(iterator)
        788       def train_function(iterator):
        789         """Runs a training execution with one step."""
    --> 790         return step_function(self, iterator)
        791 
        792     else:
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in step_function(model, iterator)
        778 
        779       data = next(iterator)
    --> 780       outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
        781       outputs = reduce_per_replica(
        782           outputs, self.distribute_strategy, reduction='first')
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in run(***failed resolving arguments***)
       1266       fn = autograph.tf_convert(
       1267           fn, autograph_ctx.control_status_ctx(), convert_by_default=False)
    -> 1268       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
       1269 
       1270   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
       2732       kwargs = {}
       2733     with self._container_strategy().scope():
    -> 2734       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
       2735 
       2736   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
       3353   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):
       3354     with ReplicaContext(self._container_strategy(), replica_id_in_sync_group=0):
    -> 3355       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
       3356 
       3357   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations, experimental_hints):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        665       try:
        666         with conversion_ctx:
    --> 667           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
        668       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
        669         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
        394 
        395   if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_allowlisted(f):
    --> 396     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
        397 
        398   # internal_convert_user_code is for example turned off when issuing a dynamic
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
        476 
        477   if kwargs is not None:
    --> 478     return f(*args, **kwargs)
        479   return f(*args)
        480 
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in run_step(data)
        771 
        772       def run_step(data):
    --> 773         outputs = model.train_step(data)
        774         # Ensure counter is updated only if `train_step` succeeds.
        775         with ops.control_dependencies(_minimum_control_deps(outputs)):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_step(self, data)
        737 
        738     with backprop.GradientTape() as tape:
    --> 739       y_pred = self(x, training=True)
        740       loss = self.compiled_loss(
        741           y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       1001         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
       1002             self._compute_dtype_object):
    -> 1003           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
       1004 
       1005         if self._activity_regularizer:
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
        423     """
        424     return self._run_internal_graph(
    --> 425         inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
        426 
        427   def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
        558 
        559         args, kwargs = node.map_arguments(tensor_dict)
    --> 560         outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
        561 
        562         # Update tensor_dict.
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
        658 
        659     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
    --> 660       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
        661 
        662     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        987         inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs, input_list)
        988 
    --> 989       input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
        990       if eager:
        991         call_fn = self.call
    
    G:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
        272                              ' is incompatible with layer ' + layer_name +
        273                              ': expected shape=' + str(spec.shape) +
    --> 274                              ', found shape=' + display_shape(x.shape))
        275 
        276 
    
    ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm: expected shape=(None, None, 5), found shape=(None, 5, 1)
```

I'm not understanding the error here.
Help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks